# How to upload x3dom files to be displayed like a gallery

Tags: upload, gallery, x3d, x3dom

I've been working with x3dom for the past month and now I wan to be able to display my work, does anyone know of an uploader where I could upload the x3dom file so that it is saved in a sort of image gallery, or is the only way to do it to keep copy pasting x3dom code to an html file and then upload thru ftp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

any variety of available upload scenarios will work

x3d is all text so you can store them as flat files and upload via ftp or if you want to have a template and dynamically viewable system you could store the x3d in a database and display that db info in a dynamically generated html file